# How to update record 'pay' laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to update my 'pay' record in the DB after pressing a button in a table row, but it shows this error when pressing the button:

> ErrorException in 0db55b8fee884912074e1a4700061051aeb18bcc.php line
>   15: Undefined variable: users (View:
>   /Users/mauricio/code/cnr/resources/views/pages/users.blade.php)

I don't know why it gives me that error when I have use the users variable before in the blade file.

Here is my Registration Controller:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use DB;
use App\User;

class RegistrationController extends Controller
{

    public function updatePay(User $id)
    {
        DB::table('users')->where('id', $id)->update(['pay' => 1]);

        return view('pages.users');
    }

}
```

Welcome controller:

```
public function usersAdmin()
{
    $users = DB::table('users')->get();

    return view('pages.users', compact('users'));
}
```

Routes file:

```
// for admin only
Route::get('/users', 'WelcomeController@usersAdmin');
Route::post('/users/{id}', 'RegistrationController@updatePay');
```

Here is my view

```
@extends('layouts.master')
@section('content')

<table class="highlight">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-field="id" hidden="">ID</th>
            <th data-field="name">Nombre</th>
            <th data-field="last_name">Apellidos</th>
            <th style="text-align: right;">Acciones</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>

        @foreach($users as $user)
            <tr>
                <td>{{$user->id}}</td>
                <td>{{$user->name}}</td>
                <td>{{$user->last_name}}</td>
                <td style="text-align: right; width: 30em">
                    @if( $user->isAdmin )
                        {{"ADMINISTRADOR"}}
                    @elseif( $user->pay )
                        <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn yellow darken-2"><i class="material-icons left" style="margin:0">create</i></a>
                        <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn red darken-1"><i class="material-icons left" style="margin:0">delete</i></a>
                    @else
                        <form method="POST" action="/users/{{$user->id}}">
                            {{ csrf_field() }}
                            <button type="submit" class="waves-effect waves-light btn green lighten-1"><i class="material-icons left" style="margin:0">done</i></button>
                        </form>
                    @endif
                </td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach

    </tbody>
</table>

@endsection
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to retrieve users and send it to the view similar like this:

**Controllers:**

```
public function methodName()
{
  $users = User::all();
  return view('path.to.view')->with(compact('users'));
}
```

Also, You have two choice to use:

**First**

```
public function updatePay($id)
```

**Second**

```
public function updatePay(User $user)
{
    DB::table('users')->where('id', $user->id)->update(['pay' => 1]);
```

and instead of `return view('pages.users');` use `return redirect()->url('users');` in the `updatePay` method.

Comment: I'm already showing my users in the DB, I need to update a record in the user row. Before pressing the button for update averything works fine

Comment: Thank you, it was so obvious that I could not see it.